# Paired electrons and entanglement

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-entanglement, orbitals, pauli-exclusion-principle

Note to duplicate concerns: How is that the same question as asking if different orbitals are entangled? I am talking about paired electrons in the same orbital orientation.

Paired electrons in an atom, have anticorrelated spin (pauli exclusion principle).
Does that mean they are entangled?

I am asking this because I assume that their spin anticorrelation is maintained inside their orbital orientation with a relative stability as long electrons do not move to other orbital positions or be ejected from the atom. So I assume a sort of connection makes sure they keep this anticorrelated state and this seems similar to an entanglement.

Comment: Yes. You answered your own question just by stating that they have a (anti) correlation. Entanglement means that there is a state of correlation between the two.

Comment: The duplicate might seem different because it asks about different orbitals, but the answer is exactly the same because the two orbital states that differ only in spin are two different quantum states in the same way as two orbital states that differ in any other quantum number. As the answer there says, the electrons in the atom are usually modeled by the (fully entangled) Slater determinant over all occupied states.

Comment: @josephh OK, I thought pauli exclusion principle only meant that electrons had to have complementary spins in order to be at the same location, not that this would produce entanglement.

Comment: @ACuriousMind OK, thank you for clarifying, I appreciate.

Comment: No problem. Did you find the answer you were looking for in the linked question or the comment above by ACuriousMind? I ask because it appears you voted to reopen this one. Cheers.